# How to migrate existing stored procedures to use graphql

Tags: graphql

I have a legacy project which uses 700+ complex stored procedures to fetch and modify data. Is there a way to use Graphql to create an API without changing the stored procedures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the language you are working in, there may be GraphQL libraries that are stored-procedure aware. If not, you can write your own.

You can also write a thin REST layer and layer GraphQL over that.

Edit:
If you're using ASP.NET Core, check out [this library](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/) and follow the examples in their documentation's introduction page, except replace the hard-coded data with calls in the library you would usually use to communicate with SQL Server to fetch the required data. I recommend [Dapper](http://dapper-tutorial.net/) (it was actually [written by the folks at Stack Overflow](https://www.infoq.com/news/2011/04/dapper-released)!) as it will let you write lightweight queries like `conn.Query("[dbo].myFooProc @bar @baz", new { bar = quux, baz = 22 })` (or using whatever existing classes you have).

So ultimately your code would look something like

```
public class FooBarQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
  public FooBarQuery()
  {

    var MyData  = conn.Query("[dbo].myFooBarProc @FooId", new { FooId = 2 }).ToList(); 
    Field<FooType>(
      resolve: context => MyData; 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, I am using Asp.net core and no entity framework to support, is there any good documentation or samples that i can use?. Thanks for the support Hugo

Comment: Awesome, just what i am looking for. Thanks

Comment: I think the link to 'this library' should be https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/introduction
it currently has a 404

Comment: Thanks @samwa! I fixed the link